# Eigenvalues and characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

In my linear algebra test, there is a true false question I couldn't understand, I was hoping someone here could explain it to me. It's the following:

Let A be a $2 \times 2$ matrix with characteristicc polynomial $p(x) = x^2+2x+1$, is it true or false that:

If $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ is the identity matrix.

The answer says this is false but I don't understand why. Any help with this question is highly appreciated!

Comment: Note that the root of $x^2+2x+1$ is $-1$, not $1$.

Comment: Oh, ok. If the root was 1, then it would be true?

Comment: In the case of a double root of $1$ for a $2 \times 2$ matrix it would be true, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Consider a matrix of the form:

$$
A= \begin{bmatrix}
1&a\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
or
$$
B= \begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
b&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
These matrices have eigenvalues $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$ but are not diagonalizable.

Comment: One can also observe that a $2\times2$ matrix with an eigenvalue of multiplicity $2$ is diagonalizable if and only if it is diagonal.